# How to determine if thread is doing an action

Tags: java, multithreading

I have simple class thats extends thread class it has run method which looks like this:

```
public void run() {

    while(running) {

        if(enabled)
        {
            doStep();
            enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                this.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other place in my code I'm calling, when I want `myObject` to call `doStep()`

```
myObject.enbled = true;
```

But how can make i sure that `myObject` actually has finished `doStep()` method? simple

```
myObject.enable = true
while(myObject.isEnabled())
{
;
}
doActionAfterObjectFinish();
```

sometime cause program to stuck in the loop, and for sure `doStep()` does not cause it.

@thanks for answers instead of using sempahores woudlnt it help if i change code in such way ?

```
    public void run() {

        while(running) {

            if(enabled)
            {
                synchronized(this){
                doStep();
                enabled = false;
}
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    this.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

public synchronized boolean isEnabled() {
return enabled;
}
```

Comment: A first idea would be to add a counter which counts how often doStep() was executed. Add counter++ below the doStep method. Then you can query the counter ln outer while like myObject.getRuntimes() > 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One, make sure that the `myObject.enable` variable is declared as `volatile`.

Two, I suggest to use `java.util.concurrent` package for what you are trying to model... may be a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) can help you...

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyRunnable target = new MyRunnable();
    Thread thread2    = new Thread(target);

    thread2.start();
    target.waitUntilFinish();

    System.out.println("MyRunnable ends first!");
  }


  public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Semaphore workDone = new Semaphore(0);
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // heavy work here...
            if (this.count < 5) {
                System.out.println("Iteration: " + (++this.count));
            } else {
                this.workDone.release();
                break;
            }
            try { Thread.sleep(2000L); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
    }

    public void waitUntilFinish() throws InterruptedException {
        this.workDone.acquire();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: shoudl my class that is calling `my.Object.isenaled()` have access to semaphore which woudl be inside `myObject'?

Comment: Thanks for answer and example! I accept it, woudl you be so kind and check if my edited code which uses `synchronized` woudl not work in the same way?

Comment: and who will release semaphore after checking?

Comment: @whd, yes your code works the same way... but remember to declared your variable `enable` as `volatile`; or change its value at a synchronized method or synchronized block code (as your wrote)...

Comment: About the semaphore releasing.... it depends... The semaphore can be release in any place or thread (JAVA don't impose any restriction about it)... So, it must be released where it has more logic to do it... In my example, the semaphore starts "taken", so any invocation on "waitUntilFinish" always blocks (in fact, blocks the main thread), until the "run" method released it...  At that point the main thread can go on and release the semaphore too...

Answer (score 0):

When you are using multithreading on CPU's is highly recommended to use semaphores or locks. Take a look at this: [A java's aproach to Spinlocks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html) and [Oracle documentation of semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Esentially, you must set a semaphore or spinlock to block the code when you need it and unlock it when it's needed. Is a common and highly recommendable practice to take.

A pseudocode aproach of spinlocks which could be usefull for you is:

```
void thread1(){
   while(true){
      while(locked(lock1));

      lock(lock2);
      doActions();
      unlock(lock2);
   }
}

void thread2(){
  while(true){
      while(locked(spinlock2));

      lock(spinlock1);
      doStuff();
      unlock(spinlock1);
  }

}
```